# 301 Redirect issue, spaces in old URL?

Tags: http-status-code-301

I have a ton of 301 Redirects set up from an old site to a new one (which is running on Joomla 1.6, but that shouldn't matter.)

I have some old url's that have spaces in them, for example: 
Redirect 301 /city/Louisiana_New%20Orleans http://www.nutcracker.com/yourcity/new-orleans-la

So in my .htaccess file, regardless if I leave the space as a space (between New and Orleans), or leave the %20, it just goes 404, and does not pickup up the new url.

Any suggestions I can try?

Thanks!
Bill

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the URL in double quotes? Something like:
`Redirect 301 "^/city/Louisiana_New Orleans$" http://www.nutcracker.com/yourcity/new-orleans-la`
should work

Answer (score 6):

This issue is resolved.  Putting the original url in quotes with a literal space solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

RewriteRule ^/city/Louisiana_New\sOrleans$ http://www.nutcracker.com/yourcity/new-orleans-la

Comment: I tried raplcing my original redirect line with both;

RewriteRule ^/city/Louisiana_New\sOrleans$ http://www.nutcracker.com/yourcity/new-orleans-la

and

Redirect 301 "^/city/Louisiana_New Orleans$" http://www.nutcracker.com/yourcity/new-orleans-la

And no luck, still going 404.