# htaccess with spaces and %20

Tags: .htaccess, spaces

I have trolled through Stack Overflow and tried every answer given, but cannot solve my issue. I redesigned my site and am trying to correct 404 errors using Redirect 301. Here is what I have tried and all options fail:

Redirect 301 /wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/high-res/8V%20Beat%20Lehigh%20Mascot%20Greensboro%20North%20Carolina.jpg http://taketheleap.ca/wp-ttld-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/8v-beat-lehigh-mascot-greensboro-north-carolina.jpg

RewriteRule ^/wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/high-res/8V Beat Lehigh Mascot Greensboro North Carolina.jpg http://taketheleap.ca/wp-ttld-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/8v-beat-lehigh-mascot-greensboro-north-carolina.jpg [R=301, NE]

I have tried Redirect 301 with %20s, with spaces, and RewriteRule with %20s and spaces. All of them fail.

I know I am missing something obvious, but do not know what it is. Help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
[301 Redirect issue, spaces in old URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235383/301-redirect-issue-spaces-in-old-url)

Essentially, this: Putting the original url in quotes with a literal space solved the problem.

So, my Redirect is now this:

Redirect 301 '/wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/redux/high-res/34 Rome - Victor Emmanuel II Monument Tomb of the Unknown Soldier.jpg' http://taketheleap.ca/wp-ttld-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/redux/34-rome-victor-emmanuel-ii-monument-tomb-of-the-unknown-soldier.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) we see that rewriterule matches against the % decoded version.  So put \s for the space characters
`^/wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/high-res/8V\sBeat\sLehigh\sMascot\sGreensboro\sNorth\sCarolina\.jpg` ...

Comment: Just tried, failed.

Specifically, tried this:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/high-res/8V\sBeat\sLehigh\sMascot\sGreensboro\sNorth\sCarolina\.jpg http://taketheleap.ca/wp-ttld-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/8v-beat-lehigh-mascot-greensboro-north-carolina.jpg [R=301]

Comment: I honestly can't tell you why it's not working.  My guess is your rewrite rules arn't being picked up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a space. I recently ran into the same problem. So if you are trying to redirect from or to a url that uses character encoding, just use the character.

Use: http://somesite.com/?a-value=some thing
Instead of: http://somesite.com/?a-value=some%20thing

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried this and it produced a 500 error, likely because it sees too many spaces. I even tried adding in a [NE] clause:

RewriteRule ^/wp-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/redux/high-res/34 Rome - Victor Emmanuel II Monument Tomb of the Unknown Soldier.jpg http://taketheleap.ca/wp-ttld-content/themes/taketheleap/images/52week/redux/34-rome-victor-emmanuel-ii-monument-tomb-of-the-unknown-soldier.jpg [NE,R=301]